# Jquery multiselect clear the options selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multi-select

I'm using jquery multiselect in my application and it works fine. I have a requirement where at some point of time I have to clear the multiselect button (options selected) and reset it to initial state with the placeholder and options. I have tried using

`$('select[multiple]').multiselect('reload');`

which does not clear the selection in my case, and

`$('select[multiple]').multiselect('unload');`

which completely removes the widget.

The link for github repo of multiselect widget I'm using is here:
[https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect](http://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect)

Seeking help! Thanks :)

Comment: Better to `unload` and then reinitialize the plugin again

Comment: @PranavCBalan Tried that too, didn't work.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet or http://jsfiddle.net